# Phonegap 2.5.0 geolocation not working with android 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, geolocation

I am trying geolocation phonegap(version 2.5) API with my android 4.0.4 device but i am getting nothing. i am using code from phonegap documentation. According to them "if GPS and wifi are disabled it should locate you using ***Cell Tower triangulation***" but this code gives nothing for me. When I connected to wifi it gives me perfect location but when there is no internet, it will not work. I am successfull with all other phonegap API's but only geolocation API is giving problem to me. Please help me to solve this.

And one more doubt pls forgive me if it seems funny doubt....
I use wifi connection in my mobile and never connected to other services(2G,3G etc), Does finding location using wifi means only wifi internet or it aslo includes 2g and 3g connections?

Thnaks in Advance

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
      <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Got to know one thing.. It will not work with 2g and 3g.. works only with WIFI

Comment: does it work now? I've the same problem.. :P

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, at first I thought it might have something to do with PhoneGap or Android (may be a compatibility issue or something). But later, i found out that I was missing a `config.xml` file in the root folder (along with `index.html`) of PhoneGap assets (HTML, CSS, JS).

I then created a `config.xml` file and put all necessary permission, features etc. and the problem solved.

You might wanna take a look at the config.xml file:
http://bit.ly/gap-config

Line 25 has the permission for Geolocation API.

If you are missing this `config.xml` file, I suggest you to go through the file from the URL above, and fill up/remove information needed for application to work properly.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in android phonegap we add permission in androidmanifest file not config file.. thats for IOS

Comment: Well, That's solved my problem for Android 4.0.4, btw I build manually using PhoneGap Build service, not Eclipse with ADT.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post.. but you could try replacing ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

worked for me =D